# Angular 2 - How to make http get request to rest api and store in json object

Tags: rest, api, angular, typescript, angular2-services

I'm trying to make get request to github api in Angular2, the data is in json format, I just need to store it in a json object.

In the Angular2 documentation

```
getHeroes (): Observable<Hero[]> {
  return this.http.get(this.heroesUrl)
                  .map(this.extractData)
                  .catch(this.handleError);
```

Since the Hero[] variable can't be defined for the api as in the documentation where it has id and name, how can I create an Observable function to get data and store it in an object.

In Angular 1.5 I've done it like this

```
  var urlBase = 'https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=';
    var SearchOp = {};
    SearchOp.getRepositories = function (search) {
        SearchOp = $http.get(urlBase+ search +'&sort=star&order=desc&per_page=5')
        return SearchOp;
    };
```

I'm doing it like this

```
 search (term: string) {

    let gitUrl = 'https://api.github.com/search/repositories';
    let params = new URLSearchParams();
    params.set('q', term); 

    let result = this.http
               .get(gitUrl, { search: params })
               .map(request => request.json());
               console.log(result);
               return result;
  }
```

but in console I'm getting

'Observable {_isScalar: false, source: Observable, operator: MapOperator}'

Not the correct result

Comment: What does "Hero[] variable can't be defined for the api" mean? What is the problem? How does `extractData` look like?

Comment: It's given in the angular2 doucmentation

Comment: Looks fine, so what's the problem?

Comment: I just want to convert the 1.5 version to angular 2, how can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

The `http.get()` call is async. This means `request => request.json` is a callback added to `map(...)` that is called when the response from the server arrives. The HTTP call is just enqueued in the browsers event queue for later execution and immediately continues to process the code in your `search` method.

Therefor `console.log(result)` is called even before the call to the server was sent.

If you want code to be executed when the data arrives, move it inside `map(...)`

```
return this.http
           .get(gitUrl, { search: params })
           .map(request => {
             request.json()
             console.log(result);
             // return result; // doesn't work
           });
```

You also can't just return the `result` because when the function is completed, the `result` is not yet available.

With above code `result` gets an `Observable` assigned that one can subscribe to.

For example this line assigns the response to `this.data` when it arrives

```
this.search(term).subscribe(data => this.data = data);
```